# redirects and SEO

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

How is the best way to redirect multiple domains to one domain? It's a multilingual website

I have read that pointing more domains to one could influence the ranking on search engines in a poor way?

ie

```
www.domain.dk -> www.domain.com/dk
www.domain.de -> www.domain.com/de
```

Is it ok to do 301 redirects? Would it influence the ranking for www.domain.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The redirects would need to be [301 redirects](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)
2. [Pointing more then one domain to your website will not offer you any SEO benefits](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this/3778#3778)

Comment: thanks.. I am not looking for benefits.. I would just make sure that it wouldnt influence the ranking in a poor way

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a very beneficial way of doing things, because it consolidates domain value from backlinks into a single .com domain rather than spreading them across multiple domains. I'd recommend subdomains (so you can do things like ch.domain.com/de & ch.domain.com/fr for German Swiss and French Swiss, but folders work too.)

You should always use 301 redirects to preserve domain value

You can then use:

- Hreflang rel=alternate tags to specify languages if you have more than one language per location (i.e. .com/dk may support english and danish)http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077
- Google Webmaster Tools localisation
- Canonical tags as appopriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use 301 redirects for redirect current Url to New one Urls.so that google will understand that this url is redirect from this to this.

Create a `.htaccess` file with the below code, it will ensure that all requests coming in to domain.com will get redirected to www.domain.com 
The `.htaccess` file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Please REPLACE domain.com and www.newdomain.com with your actual domain name.

> **Note** This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

Comment: Yes. you are write. .htaccess works only Linux Servers. & In Windows we can't do .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

> Use 301 redirect because it is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the HTTP status codes for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301 redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website.

Source: http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection